# VS2010 Load Test: Cannot connect to test controller

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I am setting up a load test controller and agents. I followed these guidelines:

- [Installing and Configuring Visual Studio Agents and Test and Build Controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd648127%28VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Using a Test Controller and Test Agents in a Load Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400223.aspx) - Setting up the load test to use the controller.

Setting up the controller and agents was quite straightforward. Both of these services run under a local user named "LoadTest" which is member of the local Administrators group.

As the next step, *[Create a new Test Setting that Uses the Test Controller and Test Agents and Data and Diagnostic adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400223.aspx#21fbe8ca-2431-4807-b11a-d4bb97411f64)*, I added a new "Test Settings" file to the solution items of my Visual Studio 2010 solution. Thereby I fail when trying to define the controller to be used in the Roles tab:

[image: Roles tab of the Test Settings]

I entered "localhost:6901" as the controller, then a warning icon appeared to the right. If I hover over that, it says:

> Cannot connect with controller 'localhost'. If the controller service is not started you may be able to start it by clicking the restart rig button.
>
> The following error was received:
>   You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this action.

I am running Visual Studio in my personal user account, which is different to the user that runs the test controller ("LoadTest"). But I reckon that this should be the normal usage scenario. Further, me as well as the "LoadTest" user are members of the administrators group.

Can anybody tell me why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the "[Troubleshooting Guide for Visual Studio Test Controller and Agent](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/df043823-ffcf-46a4-9e47-1c4b8854ca13/)" which says:

> 2.2.1. Permissions: Test Controller not connected to TFS server:
>
> - To run tests remotely, Client user must belong to either TeamTestControllerUsers, or TeamTestControllerAdmins, or Administrators local group on Controller machine.
> - To manage Controller/Agent, Client user must belong to TeamTestControllerAdmins or Administrators local group on Controller machine.
> - Agent service account must belong to either TeamTestAgentService or Administrators local group on Controller machine.
> - Controller service account must belong to either TeamTestControllerUsers or Administrators local group on Controller machine.
> - Service accounts with empty/no passwords are not supported.

Even though my personal user account already *is* in the local Administrators group, this seems not to suffice though. So I added the user to the TeamTestControllerUsers group, too, and that fixed it.

Comment: I wanted to add another solution here - When I originally encountered this error, I resolved it by running Visual Studio as an administrator.